# Update widget on document.readyState changes

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to change my widget icon (to an ajax-loader.gif) while a page is loading in a tab. 
That means after I open a new tab i want my standard widget icon, but after I tipped in a http address and press enter I want to show the gif animation until the page-loading is done. After the loading is done, the icon changes depending on a score (this works already). How can I do that?

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Showing some non-working code would improve this question.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK already gives [examples](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html) on how to get notified for various tab events using the [`tabs`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html) module :

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.on('open', function(tab){
  tab.on('ready', function(tab){
    console.log("DOM is ready", tab.url, );
    console.log("Tab is actually active", tab == tabs.activeTab);
  });
});
```